# How to load next row on button click event using C# and SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, button, picturebox, sqldatareader

I have a `PictureBox` where images are retrieve from an SQL database. What I'm trying to do is to load the next image on the click event of next button.

```
public void nextcloth(SqlConnection conn ,SqlCommand comd )
{
    try
    {
        string sql = "select productPIC from product where productType = 'Fabric'";
         if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
         {
            conn.Open();
         }

        comd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = comd.ExecuteReader()
        while (dr.HasRows)
        {
            byte[] img = (byte[])(dr[2]);
            if (img == null)
            {
                p.Image = null;
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                p.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**The button code**

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    obj.nextcloth(con, cmd);
    pictureBox2.Image = obj.getpic();
    pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table should have a pictureOrderIndex field. Then you can grab all pictureOrderIndex values for that ProductType and store them in an array. Each time the button is click move to the next item in the array and use that value from the array to get to the next picture in the product table.

public class MainClass {

private int[] imagesIndexArray; 
   private int imageCurrentIndex;

public void MainMethod(...) {
          imageCurrentIndex = 0;
          string sql = "select pictureOrderIndex from product where productType = 'Fabric'";
          // run sql and populate imagesIndexArray. I know you can finish this part.

}

public void nextcloth(SqlConnection conn ,SqlCommand comd )
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "select productPIC from product where productType = 'Fabric' AND pictureOrderIndex = " +  imageCurrentIndex.toString();
            // the rest of your code......
           //don't forget to increase the index after a success call has been made

```
         imageCurrentIndex++;
```